# Raspberry pi for smart mirror, what operating system?

Tags: pi-3, linux, operating-systems, android

I am conducting a larger project where i will create a smart mirror powered by an raspberry pi 3 B. The smart mirror will be able to use some google play application and the system will also be able to handle audio and video recording. The display will be interactive by the use of a PCT touch foil.

So the big question is what kind of operating system that suits this project.
Android or linux?

Answer (score 1):

Because Android is so under-developed on the Raspberry Pi I would definitely go with Raspbian. There is much more support and more packages available and there are already smart mirrors that have been made with Raspbian as the OS to guide you.

Android would be nice if it worked on the Pi but there are still thousands of bugs and right now its more at a proof of concept stage than an actual working platform for developing.